# How to use user input in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I am using omnet++ for my experiment.
But, I want to experiment with my input not fixed input.
I do not know which API to use user input
How to use user input during simulation?

Answer (score 1):

OMNeT++ simulations are written in C++, so you can use the full power of C++ libraries to read from files, the network, a gamepad, a kinect, etc to influence running simulations. Just create a simulation module that repeatedly reads data from such a source, e.g., once every simulated millisecond, then sends cMessages or changes modules' parameters in reaction to what it reads.